# Ideas for lowest power power solution for two wireless devices to acknowledge each others presence periodically

Tags: signal, embedded, transmitter, iot

Hi I am working on a super low power solution for two novelty items that are going to be tiny and have to have the lowest power consumption possible.
Basically what I'm trying to pull off is having one or two LEDs light up (maybe depending on signal strength) when the two devices notice each others signals. I want to create some jewlery for me and my loved one to react when we are close to each other and the electronics will have almost no room and the tiniest power source possible. It is very likely they will lose power frequently but all they need to do is identify and acknowledge each other in periods of maybe 10-15 seconds. I will probably use an AtTiny and some other smd parts for the "brains".

So my general thinking was the signal had to be distinguishable, identifiable and low power. Since there are already a lot super low power wifi modules I was contemplating using one of those.
Zigbee is also an option because as far as my understanding goes it uses AES and is even lower power than Wifi. But is there something even simpler? Something that works as a module and can be used to transfer and acknowledge signals and uniquely identify the sender while using as little power as possible? I'm talking about scraping off every milliwatt or even microwatt I can. Any ideas?

Comment: Start by figuring out the maximum size of battery that is acceptable and find a battery. Then add that detail to your question. Next consider that maximum acceptable antenna size (in three dimensions) and add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at sub-1GHz products, i.e. those using the 433 or 868 MHz bands. They generally have greater range and are less power-hungry than 2.4 GHz units, and they can be used to send a very short proprietary message, which occupies much less RF time and CPU time than the standard protocols (such as Zigbee).

Also bear in mind that it isn't just the transmission that consumes power; reception does as well. So you want the RF chip to be powered down, and the CPU sleeping, for the maximum amount of time. This raises the question of how to synchronise one unit's transmission with the other's reception, and the answer to that will depend on your power budget, and the maximum time you can allow for the units to recognise each other's presence.

Comment: Thanks! Great input! Are you aware of any good smd sub 1GHz modules that do a lot out of the box already? 
I know there are simpler things than Zigbee I was just migrating towards that as it seems to already include encryption which I think is the only way to reliably identify one another.
Yes I am aware I'd have to put everything to sleep as long as possible and I was also thinking about the synchronization issue.
One dumb solution could be that one is constantly sending and only periodically listening and the other is only listhening and once it gets the others signal they will switch.

Comment: The down side with these bands are: 1) not international 2) relatively narrow compared to 2.4GHz. On 2.4GHz the RFIC handles frequency allocation and spread spectrum for you, on sub-GHz you pretty much have to handle that manually. In practice you have to use narrowband FSK technology or you will occasionally get jammed.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the EESE! You've suggested some requirements -- small size, light weight, low power -- but jumped to some technology ideas -- ATTiny and Zigbee -- somewhat prematurely.

Instead, consider Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) as it's designed from the start for low energy consumption. BLE chips include a microprocessor more than sufficient for your needs, so there's no need for a second chip, and can consume very low current (< 1 uA) when asleep. By setting a long connection interval, the devices spend most of their time asleep, allowing a coin cell to last over a year.

The LEDs may be the primary power consumers. You can blink them on briefly to get a visual effect without sucking continuous power.

For beginners, it's best to choose a pre-certified BLE module, avoiding the complexities of RF and antenna design, and keeping parts count low. Your finished product may need just a BLE module, a coin cell battery, the LED's and a few SMD resistors.

Comment: What a great Idea thank you so much! Yes I agree my thought process is all over the place. I still wanted to include my ideas to give a better picture of what possibilities I covered already and where I want to go with this. I only have electronics knowledge from the internet and from fooling around. I have a background in computer science.
you're right bluetooth should have more than enough range for what I am trying to do. I wasn't aware that they come with micros. Is it hard to program those? For what I'm trying to do I'd just need some super simple code

Comment: @Jeffrey some BLE chips have Arduino compilers available, which should work for prototyping. To get the absolute lowest power consumption, you'll want to use the chip's native SDK and write your firmware in C.